# prevent unwanted access to back-end system with facebook login

Tags: iphone, security, facebook-graph-api, facebook, integration

I'm writing an iphone application which uses facebook login. When the user logs in the fb access token, email address is sent to an back-end DB over a web service. Now the problem is how am I going to recognize it when the access token is changed by facebook. Someone could just sent similar data to my DB over the web service pretending to be the user and change the access token in my DB. I have to somehow authenticate the web service call coming from the mobile device.

How am I going to prevent such a case without giving a password to the user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no easy or really airtight solution for this.

But first of all communication to the backend should at least use SSL encryption to minimize the risk for a man in the middle attack.

One way would be to generate a unique identifier on the first run, and use the same algorithm on the server to validate, thus creating your own kind of access token to your backend. However is your algorithm weak or anyone decompiles your application the can find out how you generate your identifier.

You should atleast use sha encryption, md5 is starting to get weak nowdays.

Exampel for a very simple token generation, do not use this in your code;

```
String salt = "twsg23s¤#"; //a random generated string (must be the same on the server and client
String token = sha1(sha1(facebookid + salt) + salt); //this will be your token
```

Then you generate the same token server side and compare the client token with the servertoken.

**I must emphasize:** Is your salt revealed and/or your algorithm weak you will have a huge security hole in your system.